# Vue component not updating property correctly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a `chat` component that has a `multiline textbox` and the `chat room` where the `messages` goes, the multiline textbox starts with a single line with `44px` of `height`, when the user types its grows and the `chat room` get smaller as seen in the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

I get that behavior with the next code

```
//chat room in the chat-room i use css variables to calculate the height
//template
<vue-perfect-scrollbar ref="chatRoomScrollbar" :style="css">
    <div  v-viewer="viewerOptions" class="chat-room px-3 py-3">\
        ...
    </div>
</vue-perfect-scrollbar>
//script
props: {
  textFieldSize: {
    type: Number,
    default: 44,
  },
},
computed: { 
    css() {
      return {
        '--height': `calc(310px - ${this.textFieldSize}px)`,
        '--max-height': `calc(310px - ${this.textFieldSize}px)`,
      };
    },
},
//style
.chat-room-container > .ps-container {
  height: var(--height);
  min-height: var(--max-height);
  background-color: #eceff1 !important;
}
```

and i get `textFieldSize` in the parent component when the `@input` event is fired

```
//chat-room
<chat-room
    :text-field-size="textFieldSize">
</chat-room>
// textbox
<v-text-field
    id="messageField"
    v-model="form.text"
    @input="getTextboxSize">
    <v-icon slot="append-icon">send</v-icon>
</v-text-field>
// script
data() {
    return {
        textFieldSize: 44,
    };
},
methods: {
    getTextboxSize() {
      if (document.getElementById('messageField')) {
        const height = document.getElementById('messageField').offsetHeight;
        this.textFieldSize = height;
        this.updateChatScrollbar = true;
      }
      if (this.form.text === '') {
        this.textFieldSize = 44;
      }
    },
},
```

when the user types, i get the height of the `textfield`, and pass it to the `chat room` and with css variable i get the height difference.

**THE PROBLEM**

When i select the text and delete it, or i use `ctrl+z` the value of `textFieldSize` is not beign recalculated until i type again, i have tried to use the `input` event in the text field, using a watcher in the `form.text` but none of them worked, how can make this work?

In the images below i have selected the text, then delete it, and show the `textFieldSize` value does not change

[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `@change` instead of `@input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bring up 2 points:

1. Why are you not using `$refs` in `getTextboxSize()` - I don't think it is the cause of your issue, but it certainly could be. It's just weird to see you jump into raw js when you could set a `ref="message-field"` on the `v-text-field` element and then access the element directly, *the Vue way*, using `this.$refs['message-field']`. I'm probably off with this, but whenever I have these kinds of issue with a loss of reactivity, it's usually due to something like this.
2. This is cheap and not usually best practice, but can you try putting `this.$forceUpdate()` at the end of your `getTextboxSize()` function. This is a way to tell Vue to update the layout again. I would try it, and if it solves the issue, then you know it's a type of reactivity/race-condition issue. I don't ship production code with `this.$forceUpdate()` because if you need to use it it's usually a sign of a more fundamental design issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is than Ctrl+Z does not trigger an `input` event. I think you should better not bind to `input` event of a textbox, but wach a `form.text` property for changes.

```
watch:{
    'form.text':function(){
        getTextBoxSize();
    }
}
```